# RegexKitLite Runtime Crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, runtime-error, regexkitlite

I'm overlaying the mapview and using RegexKitLite. I couldn't make it work. I've downloaded .m and .h files and added to the project. Also I tried, adding libicucore.dylib or libicucore.A.dlib or adding -licucore to other compiler flags field. Still getting the error:

> 2012-04-01 19:38:04.633 sennerdeysen[907:15803] -[__NSCFString stringByMatching:capture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88b6a00
>   2012-04-01 19:38:04.634 sennerdeysen[907:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringByMatching:capture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88b6a00'

Any idea?

Latest Xcode but the sdk is 4.3

Without ARC or anything else that iOS 5.0 SDK provides.

Here's the function in which I make a call to stringbymatching method:

```
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];

NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

NSError *error;    
NSString *apiResponse=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

if(apiResponse)
{
    NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];
    NSLog(@"%@",encodedPoints);
    return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
}
else 
{

    UIAlertView *alertView=[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hata" 
                                                      message:@"Rota çizilemedi. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyiniz." 
                                                     delegate:nil 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alertView show];
    return nil;
}
```

}

Comment: @Saphrosit Of course! :)

Comment: You know, sometimes the more the problem is stupid, the harder becomes to see it :)

Comment: Post more code around where you use this.  I just did a test and had no issue.

Comment: @wadesworld I uploaded the complete method. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see a particular problem there.  Make sure RegexKitLite.m contains the stringByMatching:capture: method.  Additionally, make sure that it's actually part of your application's target, and wasn't inadvertently added to some other target.  As I said, it worked on my test project.

Comment: I just had this problem because I hadn't added the classes to my target.  Good call @wadesworld